# Why does my root user have a different shell prompt to other users with the same shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

The root user on my CentOS 6 distro has a different shell prompt to other users that I create.

If I

> echo $PS1

for root user, I get **[\u@\h \W]\$**

If I do the same for another user, I get **\s-\v\$**

If I run

> which bash

I can see that both users are using the same shell (/bin/bash/).

Is the $PS1 variable being set differently for individual users or groups somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is set different (for users). The PS1 variable is read from the .bashrc of your home directory or /etc/profile or /etc/bash.bashrc.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it sets a different `PS1` for root in /etc/profile or /etc/bash.bashrc.

Answer (score 2):

Run `echo $SHELL`to identify your shell (`which bash` tells you where Bash is, not whether you're using it).

Answer (score 1):

To clearly tell if you at each and every command line whether you have super-user (root) privileges or not